# When Creating a new user set realmRoles - Keycloak Admin REST API

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm having a problem when assigning already existing realm roles when creating a user.
Following the documentation when creating a new user `POST /{realm}/users`, in the body parameter using the `UserRepresentation`, we have field called `realmRoles` which is optional.
I already tried to assign in the follow Schemas:

```
[
    {
        "id": "123asd-3223r-wer23rwer-werwer",
        "name": "name-of-role-1"
    },
    {
        "id": "23wedf-wefwcs-dfsdf-sdf",
        "name": "name-of-role-2"
    }
]
```

```
[
    {
        "id": "123asd-3223r-wer23rwer-werwer",
    },
    {
        "id": "23wedf-wefwcs-dfsdf-sdf",
    }
]
```

```
[ "123asd-3223r-wer23rwer-werwer","23wedf-wefwcs-dfsdf-sdf"]
```

```
[ "name-of-role-1","name-of-role-2"]
```

No of the above work. Either they are ignore, or I get an unknown error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You needs to use user's role mapping API instead of user API

```
POST {keycloak URL}/admin/realms/{my_realm}/users/{user-id}/role-mappings/realm
```

body of POST

```
[
  {
    "id": {realm_role_id},
    "name": {realm_role_name},
    "composite": false,
    "clientRole": false,
    "containerId": {my_realm_id}
  }
]
```

Detail information is official [Admin API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/) at Add `realm-level role mappings to the user` section.

[image]

Demo by Postman

#### 1 Get master access token, assign `token` environment `variable`

here is more detail how to [get master token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73570093/keycloak-v-18-how-to-manipulate-with-users-using-keycloak-api/73577215#73577215)

[image]

#### 2 Get Users list by `#1 token`

[image]

#### 3 Get user with `#2 {user id}`

[image]

#### 4 Get Realm ID with `#1 token`

[image]

#### 5 Get realm's `roles list`

[image]

#### 6 Set user's realm role mapping with `#5's realm role`

[image]

In the `body`, use array format - it means can assign with multiple realm roles

POST URL

```
http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/test/users/f3d78ca2-7bab-4aed-b1a4-8b98bf1be000/role-mappings/realm
```

`containerId` is #4's `{realm_id}`

`id` is #5 `{role_id}`

```
[
  {
    "id": "b73643c4-5375-4f9d-b6d5-65dc7c719c68",
    "name": "name-of-role-2",
    "composite": false,
    "clientRole": false,
    "containerId": "a6d347b4-3fe8-4410-bda6-54dbf8e50903"
  }
]
```

Return status should be 204 No Content.

If not, something thing wrong.

#### Finally, you can confirm that realm role assigned result.

[image]

#### If you want to confirm by API

GET API

```
http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/test/users/f3d78ca2-7bab-4aed-b1a4-8b98bf1be000/role-mappings/realm
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but you cannot add the ``realmRoles`` when creating a user? Only after creating the user correct ?

Comment: Yes, it have to add(create) user then can do add realmRoles. this is only way can do it. No way to both together. The reason, after add realmRoles, if get GET user API call, it do not include realmRoles information. It have to get /role-mappings/realm API call separately.

Comment: That is a bummer, the documentation is incorrect then. Also I was trying to get a list of users with their roles in one api call but seems there is not a way of doing it. Getting that information will take alot of time for multiple users. For each user I have to call another route n+1 problem.

Comment: This method save little time. #1 add user with user-name(ex : tom-kim), #2 get user id by GET /{realm}/users/?username="tom-kim". it gives {user_id}, #3 add realmRoles with #2's {user_id} OR, get all users an makes dictionary , Key is username, value is user_id. It will save a time too.

Comment: [This method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62404844/map-json-data-from-array-with-several-properties) can map(or filter) username and user-id only.

Comment: The problem/question above is different. I was asking if it is possible to get multiple users based on a condition with their respective roles in one call.
Instead of ``GET /{realm}/users`` and then for each user ``GET /{realm}/users/{id}/role-mappings`` .  Doing something like ``GET /{realm}/users/?withRoleMappings``

Comment: No, `GET /{realm}/users/?someName=value` only available, `GET /{realm}/users` returns JSON only keys. Examples : username, firstName, lastName or email. The `role-mappings` is not available.