# How to add realm-admin to an User using keycloak rest-api

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

When I add a role to an user, I search that client-role by name and then I get this role representation and add to the user. But I couldn't find out how to search the "realm-admin" role and how to add that to the user with rest api.

That's the url I'm using to search my client-role (GET):

```
https://{my-keycloak-url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm-name}/clients/{id}/roles/{role-name}
```

And that's the url I'm using to add this role to the user (PUT):

```
https://{my-keycloak-url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm-name}/users/{user-id}/role-mappings/clients/{client-id}
```

What's the equivalent to this "realm-admin"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the `realm-admin` role to user by this API

```
POST https://{my-keycloak-url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm-name}/users/{user-id}/role-mappings/clients/{realm-management-id}
```

with this body payload

```
[
    {
        "id":{realm-admin-id},
        "name":"realm-admin",
        "description":"${role_realm-admin}",
        "composite":true,
        "clientRole":true,
        "containerId":{realm-management-id}
    }
]
```

Get [master token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73721142/when-creating-a-new-user-set-realmroles-keycloak-admin-rest-api/73724620#73724620)

This is demo by Postman
[image]

OR curl command

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/my-realm/users/1b058869-a65d-4648-b4e2-4f5bf7430ea6/role-mappings/clients/33f00bff-d735-4402-88bc-51ea055d15c1' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer $token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '[
    {
        "id":"c8a60657-9545-4ab3-9913-0186fdb93213",
        "name":"realm-admin",
        "description":"${role_realm-admin}",
        "composite":true,
        "clientRole":true,
        "containerId":"33f00bff-d735-4402-88bc-51ea055d15c1"
    }
]'
```

GET `{user-id}` by user list API
[image]

GET `{realm-management-id}` by client list API
[image]

GET `{realm-admin-id}` by client role list API
[image]